# Using XML instead of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I run a large website and I'm looking in to the advantages of using XML to retrieve the data rather than querying the database so much in the hope of speeding things up a little.

The problem is, I have lots of AJAX requests etc. that go on across the website.

Is there any great advantages in using XML over MySQL and how reliable is it, i.e. can I update the whole XML file on every update, or will that cause other users to not have access to the XML file for a few seconds while the PHP writes the new file... or should I use PHP to look for and update just that field in the XML document (although that would still require updating the whole file)!?

Any ideas and best-practice ideas would be great here. How do stackoverflow do it?

Comment: Who gave you the idea that working with XML is faster than querying a database? Performance is not why people use XML.

Comment: *How do stackoverflow do it?* SO uses [SQL Server 2008](http://highscalability.com/blog/2009/8/5/stack-overflow-architecture.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a database sounds ideal for the scenario you describe (many concurrent accesses, many small queries and updates, etc.)

Reading and writing an XML file is definitely not going to be faster - in fact, it's likely to be much, much slower.  XML  is not a choice you would make to improve performance.

If you are having performance problems, look at optimizing your database first.

Comment: Just to add to @Pekka also consider caching results, consider memcache or even DB level caching

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do this.

Working with XML (file system) will never be faster than querying a database. Databases are used for a reason...

In answer to your last question (how do stack overflow do it). They use a database: https://data.stackexchange.com/ - Namely SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Databases are on the file system too y'know. Where do you think the store the data? (Although they can cache small tables in memory too.)

Comment: @Mark true - but I implied using non-optimized data storage methods (such as XML, JSON)

Answer (score 2):

Short and simple - databases was created for getting past the painfully slow file based systems.

Answer (score 0):

> How do stackoverflow do it?

An article from the site founder: [Back to basics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)